# processing a list of files using jq and saving output to file

Tags: json, jq, filenames

I have a list of files like so:

```
/path/to/dir1/f1.json
/path/to/dir2/f1.json
/path/to/dir1/f12.json
..
```

the json is like so:

```
{"score": 0.98}
```

I would like to use `jq` to process all these files and produce an output:

```
/path/to/dir1/f1.json,0.76
/path/to/dir2/f1.json,0.89
/path/to/dir1/f12.json,0.98
..
```

I know how to use `jq` on a single file, but would like to automate this for the list of files and produce the above output if this is possible.

Any tips on how to pipe correctly to `jq` and assemble the output would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `input_filename` to get the file names, string interpolation `"\(...)"` to compose and the `-r` flag to output text:

```bash
jq -r '"\(input_filename),\(.score)"' /path/to/*/*.json
```

```
/path/to/dir1/f12.json,0.98
/path/to/dir1/f1.json,0.76
/path/to/dir2/f1.json,0.89
```

Comment: JC this is an INSANE solution. Thank you EVER so much.